# Why are the sizes of the Mat's different?

Tags: c++, opencv, crop, opencv3.0, roi

I try to crop out a non-rectangular Mat from an image. Followed a lot of tutorials and now I implement this method for my purpose:

```
void crop(Mat src) {
Scalar mu, sigma;
meanStdDev(src, mu, sigma);

Canny(src, dst, mu.val[0] - sigma.val[0], mu.val[0] + sigma.val[0], 3, false);
cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 2, 100, 50, 100);

Vec4i current, previous;
Point pt1, pt2, ppt1, ppt2;

for (size_t i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    current = lines[i];
    pt1 = Point(current[0], current[1]);
    pt2 = Point(current[2], current[3]);

    previous = lines[i - 1];
    ppt1 = Point(previous[0], previous[1]);
    ppt2 = Point(previous[2], previous[3]);

    vector<Point> pt;
    pt.push_back(Point(previous[2], previous[3]));                              
    pt.push_back(Point(previous[0], previous[1]));
    pt.push_back(Point(current[0], current[1]));
    pt.push_back(Point(current[2], current[3]));

    Rect roi = boundingRect(pt);    
    contourRegion = src(roi);

    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(contourRegion.size(), CV_8UC3);
    vector<Point> ROI_Poly;
    approxPolyDP(pt, ROI_Poly, 1.0, true);
    fillConvexPoly(mask, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);

    Mat result = Mat(contourRegion.size(), CV_8UC3);
    try {
        src.copyTo(result, mask);
        imshow("result", result);
        imshow("contReg", contourRegion);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

After compiling I get the exception: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size() == mask.size()) in cv::Mat::copyTo` But why? Actually I set both `Mat`'s to `contourRegion.size` so it should be the same one?

As a reference, here's the original image: [image]

Comment: Are you sure your mask has the same size as your input image (src)?

Answer (score -1):

**Initial answer was wrong. Here is the fix**

In `copyTo` the mask is a convenience to indicate which matrix elements need to be copied, thus is has to have the same size as source `src`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4331fa88593a9a9c14c0998574695ebb). Moreover your mask has to activate all three channels. Hence, the following code should work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
vector<Point> pt;
pt.push_back(cv::Point(10, 10));
pt.push_back(cv::Point(100, 20));
pt.push_back(cv::Point(200, 300));
pt.push_back(cv::Point(10, 120));
cv::Mat src = cv::imread(argv[1]);

Rect roi = boundingRect(pt);
cv::Mat contourRegion = src(roi);

Mat mask = Mat::zeros(contourRegion.size(), CV_8UC3);
vector<Point> ROI_Poly;
approxPolyDP(pt, ROI_Poly, 1.0, true);
fillConvexPoly(mask, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);
cv::Mat f_mask = cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_8UC3);
f_mask.setTo(0);

// duplicate the mask on three channels
cv::Mat bgr_mask[3];
split(mask,bgr_mask);
cv::Mat in[] = {bgr_mask[0],bgr_mask[0],bgr_mask[0]};
cv::merge(in, 3, mask);

// copy the mask to a "full mask" of the same size as the image
mask.copyTo(f_mask(roi));

Mat result = Mat(src.size(), CV_8UC3);
try {
    src.copyTo(result, f_mask);
    imshow("result", result);
    imshow("src", src);
    cv::imshow("contReg", contourRegion);
    cv::waitKey(0);

} catch (Exception e) {}

return 0;
}
```

On the well known [lena picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png), it gives:
[image]

To get a result with the same size as `contourRegion`, let use:

```
imshow("result", result(roi));
```

You have:

[image]

Comment: Still get an exception, because I want the cropped image to be in the size of `contourRegion`.

Comment: I've edited the post to do so: let use ``result(roi)`` instead of ``result``

Comment: unfortunally, no. I just get a black image.

Comment: Can you at least reproduce my example with the ``lena.png`` image ? Else, add a link to one of your images and the exact points you want and I'll try on my side.

Comment: I already tried with your example, but it also doesn't work.. :( 
Okay, I edited my question with all needed information for you. Thank you for your effort!